# Rolling up multiple rows into a single row and column from two tables

Tags: mysql, mysqli

[image]  Here is my code

```
SELECT   
              register cr.id,
              register_cr.first_name,
              register_cr.father_name,
              register_cr.surname,
              register_cr.address,
              cr_record.charge,
              cr_record.date,
              cr_record.charge_type,
              cr_record.fir_no
FROM 
             register_cr as register_cr
INNER JOIN 
             cr_record as cr_record ON register_cr.id = cr_record.cri_reco_id
```

Comment: Do you have the right to store this data?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the output you are looking for?

Comment: yes i have right for this

Comment: Please post that as text rather then an image as there are plenty of work networks where imgur is blocked which makes people unable to help.

Comment: Formatting is better done at the application level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) allows this form of transformation:

```
SELECT   
              register_cr.id,
              register_cr.first_name,
              register_cr.father_name,
              register_cr.surname,
              register_cr.address,
              GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT cr_record.charge SEPARATOR "\n"),
              GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT cr_record.date SEPARATOR "\n"),
              GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT cr_record.charge_type SEPARATOR "\n"),
              GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT cr_record.fir_no SEPARATOR "\n")
FROM 
             register_cr as register_cr
INNER JOIN 
             cr_record as cr_record ON register_cr.id = cr_record.cri_reco_id
GROUP BY register_cr.id
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It was helpful only that the separator was not showing.